# Javascript function cannot update variable

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to update the value of a button with id 'cost' on click.
Here is my script :

```
<script>
    var costObj = document.getElementById('cost');
    function change() {
        costObj.value = 100;
    }
</script>
```

and here is the input html.

```
<input type = number id = 'cost' onclick = 'change()'>
```

This does not work saying that costObj in the function change is null, but putting the costObj declaration within the function seems to work. Why is this so ? I thought the function will look for the declaration outside the function if there is no declaration as is the case for var that has primitive type. This kind of shakes my conceptual understanding. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Is the input tag defined before that script tag?

Comment: @Musa Yes that is the most likely problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code is put into a Stack Overflow "snippet" like this, it works as expected:

```js
var costObj = document.getElementById('cost');
function change() {
    costObj.value = 100;
}
```

```html
<input type = number id = 'cost' onclick = 'change()'>
```

I think the culprit is likely to be what @Musa noted in a comment: make sure that your script appears *after* the `<input>` tag, otherwise the `cost` element will not exist at the time you try to get a reference to it.

It works in the snippet because the JavaScript code is loaded after the HTML code. Note that Stack Overflow's presentation of the snippet is a bit misleading, as it displays the HTML below the JavaScript.

To help illustrate this, here are two more versions of the snippet with everything included in the HTML section instead of using the separate JavaScript section. This way we can control whether the HTML or JavaScript code is loaded first.

This one fails because the `script` is included before the `input` tag:

```html
<script>
    var costObj = document.getElementById('cost');
    function change() {
        costObj.value = 100;
    }
</script>

<input type = number id = 'cost' onclick = 'change()'>
```

This one succeeds because the `script` is included *after* the `input` tag:

```html
<input type = number id = 'cost' onclick = 'change()'>

<script>
    var costObj = document.getElementById('cost');
    function change() {
        costObj.value = 100;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it is the problem! Thanks for helping out ! I did not know that the ordering mattered in this case haha, Now I know

Answer (score -1):

you should to try to add event listener on the object and change var to const for best way  and dont use onclick below the html code because its looks like old way to call the function just execute the function inside the listener event

**for example**

```js
    const costObj = document.getElementById('cost');
    costObj.addEventListener("click" , function(){
        change();
    }); 
    
        function change() {
            costObj.value = 100;
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cost" />
```

Answer (score -2):

put below js code and replace onClick = 'change()' with onClick = "change()"

Comment: HTML accepts single quotes or double quotes interchangeably. That is not the problem here.